# How can I get the Kubernetes external server URL from within a pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to get the **external** Kubernetes server URL from within a pod. I tried using the value of the `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` environment variable, but it gives me a URL that's only accessible from within the cluster (i.e. `api.a16fade.kyma.internal.live.k8s.example.com` instead of `api.a16fade.kyma.example.com`). Is there any way to get the external URL?

**Background:** There's a job scheduler service that schedules Kubernetes jobs for a lot of applications across different clusters via service accounts with limited permissions. Of course, it needs the external server URLs to be able to create the job resources, and they need to be provided dynamically (should not be manually hardcoded) to make it easy to swap clusters or deploy the applications in a new cluster.

Comment: In principle, this does not sound possible without support from your specific cloud provider. Maybe you could provide a ConfigMap in every cluster with the external URL/domain name?

Comment: @Garuno Yes, providing a config map is possible. I was just wondering whether there's any easy way to get the external URL from K8s itself, but I'm also starting to suspect there isn't.

Comment: Kubernetes can't know the external URL. There can be as many external URLs to your cluster as you like with different DNS providers. The best you could try is a reverse DNS lookup of your Node IP and in most setups this isn't going to work, because you have an external load balancer somewhere that is the main entrypoint to your cluster. The best you can get IMHO is a manually created config map with the external URL.

Comment: It looks like you are using kyma as your cloud provider. Theoretically they have the information necessary to provide an external URL to your cluster. So if they can provide the external URL to your cluster in a config map, that would be the way to go. Or you need to look at the DevOps tools that deploy your cluster(s). There you could also configure something, but without knowing anything about your setup, we can't help you here.